# How to create Master Switch in preferences setting activity

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

> I want to create master switch as shown in image to enable or disable all  options using android preference activity.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsA8G.png

Something like this :- https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines#master_setting

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: no yet ! but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution either but I have something similar. Maybe it helps.

I have this on top:

```
<PreferenceCategory app:title="">
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="MasterSwitch"            
        app:summaryOff="Everything is disabled"
        app:summaryOn="Everything is enabled"
        app:title="This is a master switch (more or less)"
        />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

And then, every PreferenceCategory depends on the above (app:dependency="MasterSwitch"). So, if the "MasterSwitch" is disabled, all categories below are displayed as disabled. Set the Categories this way:

```
<PreferenceCategory
        app:dependency="MasterSwitch"
        app:title="Another category">

        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="signature"
            app:title="Option 1"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
</PreferenceCategory>

and so on...
```

The problem is that I cannot set the nice blue or gray background color that you showed here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines#master_setting

I cannot have the information box it is shown there either.

Comment: good but i want to set background color. thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in Settings Activity or Fragment. There are  a lot of tutorials on YouTube.

New -> Activity -> Settings Activity

Comment: please look at the image first i want to create master switch in setting activity

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).